# angular bootstrap, modal scope doesn't get destroyed when view changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scope, modal-dialog

OK so I've tried Googling for it and have read several of the various questions posted on here, but none seem to address the issue I have currently.

I'm working with angular and using the angular-bootstrap ui. When the user clicks on the login button on the homepage a modal pops up giving them options. I can sign in through Facebook, Twitter, etc just fine. But when the new user welcome page the scope for the modal instance is still there. This isn't a huge issue but annoying and I'd rather not have unnecessary scope creep slowing down my client side.

Here a walk through of my issue using pictures. So the user hits the homepage as seen below.(ok I couldn't post images because my reputation isn't a 10 so here's a link to them.)

https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/1538681_313638755452846_5694320198249084494_n.jpg

As the photo shows the scope is limited to that of the controller for the view. Then the user clicks on the Login button and the modal pops up. (As can be seen in the following link)

so it wouldn't let me post more than 2 links because my reputation isn't a 10 so I had to disguise this one.

https (remove me)://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/1926680_313638758786179_2230027955019442405_n.jpg

If you look at the scope you'll see that I've circled in red the newly added scope for the modal. When the user selects a provider to log-in with he/she is taken to the new user page as can be seen in the following link.

https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10155397_313638762119512_900295349985269066_n.jpg

A portion of the modal scope is still present, even though it's not in use anymore. I don't know how to remove it. True if I reload the page the scope will disappear but I don't want to force a reload simple to remove scope. Especially when it's not currently noticeable or slowing it down. Is there a way to remove this scope without a reload?

Here's my current code.

The Controller:

```
'use strict';

   angular.module('triviumApp')
    .controller('HomepageCtrl', function ($log, $modal, $scope, UserFactory, $location) {
        $scope.user = UserFactory;

        $scope.awesomeThings = [
            'HTML5 Boilerplate',
            'AngularJS',
            'Karma'
        ];

        $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

        $scope.close = function (){
            $modal.close();
        };

        $scope.login = function (type){
            console.log("hi");
            $scope.user.login(type);
        };

        $scope.open = function () {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'LoginModalContent.html',
                controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                resolve: {
                    user: function () {
                        return $scope.user;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (provider) {
                //They logged in
                $scope.user.login(provider);
            }, function (event) {
                //the Modal was dismissed so the user didn't log in.
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date() + event);
            });
        };


    }
   );


   // Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
   // It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

   var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
      $scope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };

      $scope.login = function (provider){
          $modalInstance.close(provider);
      };
    };
```

Here's the View:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li ng-show="user.getLoginStatus"><a href="" ng-click="open();">Login</a></li>
        <!--<li ng-show="user.getLoginStatus"><a href="" ng-click="user.logout();">Logout</a></li>-->
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Temp Title</h3>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="LoginModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="bold">Login/Sign-up</legend>

            <div class="login-icons center-block">
                <a href="" ng-click="login('facebook');"><span class="facebook icon"></span></a>
                <span><a href="" ng-click="login('github');"><span class="github icon"></span></a></span>
                <!--<span><a href="" ng-click="login('google');"><span class="google icon"></span></a></span>-->
                <span><a href="" ng-click="login('persona');"><span class="persona icon"></span></a></span>
                <span><a href="" ng-click="login('twitter');"><span class="twitter icon"></span></a></span>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here's the User Factory -- (Note I removed my firebase key so it won't have access to my firebase account so if you test it you'll need to add your key and setup your Firebase account to work with Facebook, or twitter.

```
'use strict';

var User = angular.module('UserApp', ['firebase']);

User.factory('UserFactory', ['$firebase', '$window', function ($firebase, $window){
    //Firebase Variables
    var user = {
        'name': null,
        'id': null,
        'address': null,
        'email': null,
        'gender': null,
        'loggedIn': false
    };

    var firebase = new Firebase("YOUR FIREBASE KEY HERE");
    var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(firebase, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            // an error occurred while attempting login
        } else if (user) {
            // user authenticated with Firebase
            console.log('Auth', response);
            if(response !== null) {
                getUser(response);
            }
        } else {
            // user is logged out
        }
    });

    function getUser(firebaseInfo){
        if(firebaseInfo !== null && firebaseInfo.firebaseAuthToken !== null){
            user.id = firebaseInfo.firebaseAuthToken.split('.')[0];

            firebase.child(user.id).once('value', function(snap){
                if(snap.val() === null){
                    populateUser(firebaseInfo, snap, true);
                }
                else{
                    //Check to see if user used a different provider
                    populateUser(firebaseInfo, snap, false);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    function populateUser (firebaseInfo, snap, newUser){
        var provider = firebaseInfo.provider;

        //Create the user in the firebase table
        firebase.child(user.id);

        if(provider === 'facebook'){
            if(newUser){
                console.log('Here');
                facebookUser(firebaseInfo);
                $window.location.href ='/#/new-user';
            } else{
                if(!snap.val().Facebook_ID){
                    facebookUser(firebaseInfo);
                }
            }

        } else if(provider === 'github'){
            if(newUser){
                githubUser(firebaseInfo);
                $window.location.href('/new-user');
            } else{
                if(!snap.val().GitHub_ID){
                    githubUser(firebaseInfo);
                }
            }
        } else if(provider === 'persona'){
            if(newUser){
                personaUser(firebaseInfo);
                $window.location.href('/new-user');
            } else{
                if(!snap.val().Persona_ID){
                    personaUser(firebaseInfo);
                }
            }
        }else if(provider === 'twitter'){
            if(newUser){
                twitterUser(firebaseInfo);
                $window.location.href('/new-user');
            } else{
                if(!snap.val().Twitter_ID){
                    twitterUser(firebaseInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function facebookUser (firebaseInfo){
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'Facebook_ID': firebaseInfo.id});
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'Facebook_Link': firebaseInfo.thirdPartyUserData.link});

        user.name = firebaseInfo.name.split(' ');
        user.gender = firebaseInfo.thirdPartyUserData.gender;

        if(user.name[0] && user.name[1]) {
            firebase.child(user.id).update({'Name-First': user.name[0], 'Name-Last': user.name[1]});
        }

        if(user.gender){
            firebase.child(user.id).update({'Gender': firebaseInfo.thirdPartyUserData.gender});
        }
    }

    function githubUser (firebaseInfo){
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'GitHub_ID': firebaseInfo.id});
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'GitHub_Link': firebaseInfo.thirdPartyUserData.html_url});
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'Email': firebaseInfo.thirdPartyUserData.emails[0].email});
    }

    function personaUser (firebaseInfo){
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'Persona_ID': firebaseInfo.id});
    }

    function twitterUser (firebaseInfo){
        firebase.child(user.id).update({'Twitter_ID': firebaseInfo.id});

        user.name = firebaseInfo.name.split(' ');

        if(user.name[0] && user.name[1]) {
            firebase.child(user.id).update({'Name-First': user.name[0], 'Name-Last': user.name[1]});
        }
    }

    return {


        login: function (provider){
            if(provider !== undefined && provider !== '' && provider !== null){
                auth.login(provider);
            }
        },

        logout: function (){
            auth.logout();
        },

        getLoginStatus: user,

        getMyAddress: function (){
            return user.address;
        },

        getMyEmail: function (){
            return user.email;
        },

        getMyName: function (){
            return user.name;
        },

        updateMyName: function (first, last){
            if(user.id != null){
                firebase.child(user.id).update({'First_Name': first});
                firebase.child(user.id).update({'Last_Name': last});
            }
        },
        updateMyEmail: function (email){
            if(user.id != null){
                firebase.child(user.id).update({'Email': email});
            }
        },

        updateMyAddress: function (address){
            if(user.id != null){
                firebase.child(user.id).update({'Address': address});
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Thanks for the help. :-)